# Get all row names from empty table with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, row

I tried to get all available row names from a empty table

I can do a query with

```
SELECT * FROM tablename;
```

and get as result with vardump

```
object(mysqli_result)#95 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

There is a information about the field_count, but no names.

Comment: You can loop and fetch field names with http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php

Comment: Or you can just select them if you're not interested in the data and retrieve like normal result set `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename`

Comment: "row names"? Rows do not have names.

Comment: I don't know how it's called in english. Maybe "row title"? Or is Columns the right word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`fetch_field()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php)** to get all information about column

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* Get field information for all columns */
    while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {

    printf("Name:     %s\n", $finfo->name);
    printf("Table:    %s\n", $finfo->table);
    printf("max. Len: %d\n", $finfo->max_length);
    printf("Flags:    %d\n", $finfo->flags);
    printf("Type:     %d\n\n", $finfo->type);
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `query`

```
show columns from tablename
```

example

```
 <?php
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysql_user = "root";
    $mysql_password = "";
    $mysql_database = "user";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password,$mysql_database) or die("Could not connect database");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"show columns from student");
    $fields = array();
    $i = 0;
    while($result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $fields[$i] = $result1['Field'];
        $i++;

    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($fields);
```

Please change `database` credentials according to yours

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```